# PHP code to get value from json list with wildcard and produce array

Tags: php, json, solr, wildcard

Here is a json list (returned by solr): -

```
    {
    "suggest":{
        "mySuggester3":{
            "\"rich mal\"":{
                "numFound":2,
                "suggestions":[{
                    "term":"rich malzone and gloria didden and united marketing",
                    "weight":1,
                    "payload":""
                },
                {
                    "term":"rich malzone and united",
                    "weight":1,
                    "payload":""
                }]
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

How do I use PHP to produce an array like [ "rich malzone and gloria didden and united marketing", "rich malzone and united" ]

I've tried the following (with no luck): -

sourceArr = data.suggest.mySuggester3.*.suggestions[0]

json_decode doesn't seem to handle wildcards.

Thanks

Update: 17th Nov 2023

So, thanks to the tip from brombeer, I've used the foreach loop.   Here is my answer: -

So, after much trial and error, this is what I've come up with: -

```
    $objJson        = json_decode($data);
    $suggest        = $objJson->suggest;
    $mySuggester3   = $suggest->mySuggester3;
    $query    = $mySuggester3->rich;
    $suggestions    = $query->suggestions;
    $arrays    = $suggestions[0];
    $term          = $arrays->term;

    //var_dump($suggestions);


    $cart=array();
    foreach($suggestions as $objList){
        if(is_object($objList)){
                $term     = $objList->term;
                //print_r($term);
                array_push($cart, $term);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($cart);
    echo "\r\n";
```

?>

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use [json\_​decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to ... decode JSON in PHP. Then access the resulting array/object

Comment: "_json_decode doesn't seem to handle wildcards_" What is that supposed to mean? What wildcards? You can use loops to loop over the decoded results

Comment: Thanks @brombeer.  I've used json_decode with a foreach loop as you suggested.